# gawk join two TSV by columns (a'la sql join)

Tags: awk, csv

How to join, to tsv files, examples:

a.tsv

```
c   7   r   z
d   6   s   w
f   1   f   f
b   8   p   y
a   9   q   x
```

b.tsv

```
a   q   a
c   r   ccc
b   p   bb
0   0   0
d   s   dddd
```

Here I'd like to "join" them by columns, `where a$1,a$3==b$1,b$2` and display rest (a$2,a$4,b$3) :

```
6   w   dddd
9   x   a
8   y   bb
7   z   ccc
```

Question is: how would you do this in gawk ?

**Order of rows does not metter** (in output. In input, order of rows is not defined and can be different in a.tsv and b.tsv - like rows in relational db, they have no order).

*Uniqueness note*: Originally, I assumed "uniqueness of `key={a$1,a$3}`. As [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23186/gawk-join-two-tsv-by-columns-ala-sql-join/23189#23189) noticed - it can not be assumed from original problem statement, as it allows not unique rows according to any key - thanks [glenn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23186/gawk-join-two-tsv-by-columns-ala-sql-join/23189#23189).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears the `join` command can only join on one field [[1](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619562/joining-multiple-fields-using-unix-join/2619623#2619623)], so:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
    NR==FNR {a[$1 FS $3] = $2 FS $4; next}
    $1 FS $2 in a {print a[$1 FS $2], $3}
' a.tsv b.tsv
```

Update due to comment: since the given key is not unique, here's a technique to build up multiple entries from "a.tsv"

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
    NR==FNR {
        key = $1 FS $3
        if (key in a)
            a[key] = a[key] "\n" $2 FS $4
        else
            a[key] = $2 FS $4
        next
    }
    $1 FS $2 in a {
        split(a[$1 FS $2], ary, /\n/)
        for (idx in ary)
            print ary[idx], $3
    }
' a.tsv b.tsv
```

Comment: @glenn_jackman I have not been clear enought. Let me be more specific: there are two files, but their filenames can be fixed in sourcecode :).

Comment: @glenn_jackman: It is skips records with duplicate keys in a.tsv. It only keeps the last-read one in the array...

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki, answer updated, check it out.

Comment: @glennjackman , Thanks for pointing out uniqueness problem :).

Answer (score 3):

I'd split the task to two different programs:

1. Use *join(1)* to join the two files
2. *awk(1)* or *cut(1)* to strip unwanted columns

Comment: JOIN is interesting part. Second - cutting, is clear to me.

Comment: [join(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join).

Comment: In case I've not stated that clearly enough: There is a UNIX command named `join` which you may use for that task.

Comment: Thanks, ktf, I haven't knew before about `join` command, so I misunderstood "join" with question statement. IMHO you were right, and shown clearly that you mean command with brackets, referencing to man page - it was my misunderstood. Thanks again :D.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `awk` very well, but it was designed specifically for handling fields in text files, so I presume it can do the job quite well, but because you seemed(?) to express interest in `join` (in *ktf's* comments), here is a solution using standard unix tools: `join` and `cut` and `paste` and `sort` -- lots of "ands", but it works and it might serve as an example of why `awk` is better :)... I've thown it in mainly for then comparison-of-methods factor.

```
join -t $'\t' -o 1.2 1.3  2.2  \
 <(paste <(paste <(cut -f1 a.tsv) \
                 <(cut -f3 a.tsv) \
                 | tr '\t' '\0' ) \
         <(cut -f2 a.tsv) \
         <(cut -f4 a.tsv) \
         | sort ) \
 <(paste <(paste <(cut -f1 b.tsv) \
                 <(cut -f2 b.tsv) \
                 | tr '\t' '\0' ) \
         <(cut -f3 b.tsv) \
         | sort )
```

Comment: It's good idea to use combination of `sort`, `cut`, `paste` , as long as we could assume, that both sets have same size and all rows have matching ones. Here you can not assume that, there might be some not matching rows.

Comment: @Grzegorz Wierzowiecki: The method above *can* deal with non matching rows; it does *not* output them. `join` handles that... Re file size(rows); again this isn't a problem. `paste` must have equal numbers of rows, and it gets them if the input is properly delimited... However, on re-visiting this, I noticed a problem caused by concatenating the keys (`tr -d '\t'`), eg. — `X\tXX` will match `XX\tX` as `XXX`—   Fortunately, `tr` can cope with null chars.. Becaues the null char is not used as a delimiter, the other tools a quite okay with it (I have ammended the answer)

Comment: +1 for you fered. I've just read `man join`. Very nice tool, thanks :).

Comment: For general info:  To filter out any malformed lines (rows) which don't have the exact number of fields, you can add another filter to each *file name*.   Eg. expecting 4 fields (3 delimiters), this works:  `<(sed -nr '/^[^\t]*(\t[^\t]*){3}$/p' a.tsv)`

Comment: In my domain, if any line is malformed, I rise error that whole input has problem. So your tip is good, just to check opposite task: if all lines are correct. Good for readers you've pointed it out, thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've managed to do that. So I share my solution :

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
    while ((getline < "a.tsv") > 0){
        a2[$1,$3] = $2; a4[$1,$3] = $4
    }
}
($1,$2) in a2 { print a2[$1,$2] FS a4[$1,$2] FS $3 }' < b.tsv
```

produces:

```
9   x   a
7   z   ccc
8   y   bb
6   w   dddd
```

This solution :

- does not assume order of input rows
- works, when some rows have no matching in other file
- assume rows in `a.tsv` are unique according to `key = {a$1,a$3}`

For those interested in **right join** , you just need to delete `if( ($1,$2) in a2)` statement. For those interested in **left join**, just do "right join" version and swap a.tsv with b.tsv (and change code accordingly).

*Uniqueness note* : As [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23186/gawk-join-two-tsv-by-columns-ala-sql-join/23189#23189) noticed, that `a.tsv`'s rows might not be unique according to `key={a$1,a$3}` , you might like to check out his solution.