# Concatenating columns horizontally. Printing only rows that intersect on 1st column

Tags: zsh, awk

Say I have two different commands that output contents by columns, e.g.:

```
$ command_1

7049857 abc fdg hsi
5409858 xxx fyy hsi
540958  abc zzz hsi
54230956  rbc sss hsi

$ command_2

7049857 0 fdg free
5409858 0 fyy free
540958  2 zzz free
```

I would like to silently grab columns with indices `x,y,z` from the output of `command_1` and the columns with indices `a,b,c` from the output `command_2` and print a new output: `x,y,z,a,b,c`.

### Example:

Output the column column **1** and **2** from `commmand_2`: and the last column from `command_1`:

```
$ new_command

7049857 0  hsi
5409858 0  hsi
540958  2  hsi
```

### What I have so far:

I am relatively new to `awk`, but I know I can grab the corresponding columns from each of these commands with `awk`:

```
command_1 | awk '{print $x " " $y " " $z}'
command_2 | awk '{print $a " " $b " " $c}'
```

The above concatenates the columns vertically but I need to concatenate them horizontally.

### Printing only those rows that intersect on the first column:

Say that it is possible that `command_2` has more or less rows than `command_1`. However, the first column of both commands holds **items belonging to the same category**  (a multiple-digit ID, as in the example above)

With this, assuming that the first column of both commands are sorted equally and that new or missing entries can only happen at the end, how could we make sure that we only print those rows for which we have entries in `command_1` and `command_2` (i.e. the intersection of both commands)? (the example above shows this)

Comment: You might be interested in similar question and results: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23186/9689

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
join <(command1) <(command2) | cut -d ' ' -f 1,5,4
```

The `join` command takes files, not commands, but with a shell such as bash you can use the shown construct to turn the command output into a virtual file.

Instead of `cut` you can also use `awk`, if that's your thing.

If you find yourself doing this a lot, consider using a relational database engine.

Comment: `join` required sorted files, and you can use the `-o` option to select the output fields: `join <(command_1|sort) <(command_2|sort) -o 2.1,2.2,1.4`

Answer (score 2):

If you want awk, here's a take:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {cmd1[$1] = $NF; next}
  $1 in cmd1 {print $1, $2, cmd1[$1]}
' <(command_1) <(command_2)
```

The `FNR` awk variable is the line number within the current file.
The `NR` variable is the line number of all lines seen so far.
Thus, the condition `NR==FNR` will only be true for the first file argument.